# Using scrapy-splash clicking a button

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to use [Scrapy-splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash) to click a button on a page that [I'm being redirected to](https://pastebin.com/J6BPB4Zk).

I have tested manually clicking on the page, and I am redirected to the correct page after I have clicked the button that gives my consent. I have written a small script to click the button when I am redirected to the page, but this is not working.

I have included a snippet of my spider below - am I missing something in my code?:

```
from sys import path
import os

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
path.append(dir_path)

import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

script="""
function main(splash)
    splash:wait(1)
    splash:runjs('document.querySelector("form.consent-form").submit()')
    splash:wait(1)
    return {
        html = splash:html(),
    }
end
"""


class FoobarSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "foobar"          

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = ['https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/quote/ANTO.L?p=ANTO.L']

        for url in urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse,
                    endpoint='render.html',
                    args={'wait': 3},
                    meta = {'yahoo_url': url }
                )



    def parse(self, response):
        url = response.url

        with open('temp.html', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)

        if 'https://guce.' in url:
            print('About to attempt to authenticate ...')
            yield SplashRequest(
                                    url, 
                                    callback = self.get_price, 
                                    endpoint = 'execute',
                                    args = {'lua_source': script, 'timeout': 5},
                                    meta = response.meta 
                                )

        else:
            self.get_price(response)




    def get_price(self, response):    
        print("Get price called!")
        yahoo_price = None          

        try:
            # Get Price ...
            temp1 = response.css('div.D\(ib\).Mend\(20px\)')
            if temp1 and len(temp1) > 1:
                temp2 = temp1[1].css('span')
                if len(temp2) > 0:
                    yahoo_price = temp2[0].xpath('.//text()').extract_first().replace(',','') 

            if not yahoo_price:
                val = response.css('span.Trsdu\(0\.3s\).Trsdu\(0\.3s\).Fw\(b\).Fz\(36px\).Mb\(-4px\).D\(b\)').xpath('.//text()').extract_first().replace(',','')
                yahoo_price = val


        except Exception as err:
            pass           


        print("Price is: {0}".format(yahoo_price))


    def handle_error(self, failure):
        pass
```

How do I fix this so that I can correctly give consent, so I'm directed to the page I want?

Comment: Could you show us how you use MySpider class ? Please give a us an example that we can reproduce.

Comment: @Gelineau sample code included

Comment: I'm unable to recreate the issue. For me, `else: self.get_price(response)` was being called rather than the clause having to do with `collectConsent`. The price got collected for me. You don't do anything with it but I was able to print it out. The only other thing I changed was to print out the errors and to change `convert_to_float` to `float` since you haven't provided that function and just using `float()` works. Do you know if there's a way I can force it to ask me to collect consent?

Comment: @Zev This could be because I have greatly simplified the code I pasted here. I am trying to come up with a better example that replicates the behavior. In the meantime, however, you can easily replace this in your browser. If you open a new private session in your browser and go to the url I provided, you will see that it redirects to an authentication page. That is where my code is failing.

Comment: I think it is a location/GDPR thing: https://geopeeker.com/fetch/?url=https%3A%2F%2Ffinance.yahoo.com%2Fquote%2FIBM%3Fp%3DIBM . I'm not getting that message because I'm in the states.

Comment: I can get the same message if I go to https://uk.yahoo.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than clicking the button, try submitting the form:

```
document.querySelector("form.consent-form").submit()
```

I tried running the JavaScript command `input.btn.btn-primary.agree").click()` in my console and would get an error message "Oops, Something went Wrong" but the page loads when using the above code to submit the form.

Because I'm not in Europe I can't fully recreate your setup but I believe that should get you past the issue. My guess is that this [script](https://s.yimg.com/oa/build/js/site-c00ac266.js) is interfering with the `.click()` method.

Comment: Strange, I tried the Javascript command in Chrome browser with `document.querySelector("input.btn.btn-primary.agree").click()` and it worked, however, when I replaced `click()` with `submit()`, I got an error saying the object did not have a function named `submit()` (or words to that effect). I still am not able to get past this.

Comment: Just to make sure, did you change what you were selecting from `("input.btn.btn-primary.agree")` to `("form.consent-form")`?

Comment: Ah, I missed the fact that the selected element had changed. It's getting late here now though. I'll try tomorrow and let you know. Thanks

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli did you ever get a chance to check that out?

Comment: Yes, I tried just now and still the problem persists - can't get pass the authentication page. I have updated the code with the exact same one I am using to test this problem - and yes, I am running the code from Europe.